# How can I control focus within a Win32 app?

Tags: c++, winapi, events

I have a situation where I have a main window with a toolbar containing some edit fields.

We want the user to be able to keep focus in the edit fields and still be able to right click on the view window (both descendents of the same main window, same thread).

In current tests, I see that the focus messages happen even before the view receives the RMB down message:

1. Edit = kill focus
2. View = set focus
3. View = RMB down

I don't want to have the edit retain focus no matter what: just maintain focus if the user tries to do an RMB click on the view.

Because the focus stuff happens first, I'm a bit at a loss as to how to tell that what's about to happen is the right mouse button down.

Comment: The Windows On-Screen keyboard does this I think. I don't know how though, perhaps you should try searching about that.

Comment: It doesn't tell you that an RMB caused it, but the kill focus and set focus messages should carry the HWND or control ID of the other window.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks or is it pure unadulterated Win32 a la Petzold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by turning on the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style flag on the right-clicked window.  That stops the window manager from automatically activating the clicked window.

Comment: Thanks Hans!  I'll see if this can be leveraged into what I need.